# Finding $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\; dx$ using definition

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, definition

I believe I understand how to find definite integrals of polynomials using the limit definition. So, for example, to find $\int_0^1 x^2$ one ends up needing $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$. My question is how one would do an integral like
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\;dx
$$
using the definition. From my work I end up having to find
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}
$$
and I don't know this sum.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: It diverges....

Comment: You can't integrate from $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're talking about using the Riemann sum to calculate integrals. For example,
$$\int_0^1x^2dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}=\frac{1}{3}.$$

But the integral
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n}{i}\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}=\infty$$

diverges because the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverges.