# Finding $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}\;dx$ using limit definition

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, definition, riemann-sum

I have a follow up question to my question here:
[Finding $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\; dx$ using definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498636/finding-int-01-frac1x-dx-using-definition)

In this question I asked about $\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{x}\; dx$ and I think I understand how this integral is $\infty$.

I think the different integral
$$
\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}\;dx
$$
is actually equal to a number. My question is how one can find this integral
 *using the limit definition*.

After working on this a bit, I get
$$
\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}\;dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+i/n}\frac{1}{n}\\
=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+i/n}\\
=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+i}
$$
So I need to find
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+i}
$$
but I am not sure how I can do this. I get how you can find sums like $\sum i$, $\sum i^2$, and $\sum i^3$.

Comment: Should be $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+i}$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Thanks, I edited

Comment: @velutluna: Thanks I edited

Comment: @JohnDoe Use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660399/prove-by-induction-that-sum2n-i-1-frac-1i-1i-sumn-i-1-frac/1660408#1660408) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x).

Comment: Note that the Riemann Sum above is for $\int_0^1\frac1{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x$, which gives the same value, but *is* slightly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better subdivision in terms of simplifying the Riemann sum is with a geometric series, set $x_k=q^k$ with $q^N=2$ then the Riemann sum with the left interval points is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}f(x_k)(x_{k+1}-x_k)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{q^k(q-1)}{q^k}=N(q-1)=N(\sqrt[N]2-1)
$$
and it is a classical result that that limit is $\ln(2)$. You could consider it a difference quotient
$$
\frac{e^{\ln(2)\cdot(1/N)}-e^0}{(1/N)-0}
$$
with the obvious derivative as limit.

Answer (score 4):

The Riemann Sum in the question is not quite right (though it gives the same result). The Riemann Sum really should be
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^2\color{#C00}{\frac1x}\,\color{#090}{\mathrm{d}x}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\color{#C00}{\frac1{k/n}}\color{#090}{\frac1n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1k\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\left[\log\left(1+\frac1k\right)+O\!\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)\right]\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\log\left(\frac{2n+1}n\right)+O\!\left(\frac1{n}\right)\right]\\[12pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\log(2)}
\end{align}
$$
where we have used $x=\log(1+x)+O\!\left(x^2\right)$ and a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) employing $\log\left(1+\frac1k\right)=\log(k+1)-\log(k)$.

---

**Approach Using $\boldsymbol{\int x^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{\alpha+1}x^{\alpha+1}}+C$**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^2\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^2x^{-1+1/n}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[9pt]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(2^{1/n}-1^{1/n}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\log(2)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\log(2)/n}-1}{\log(2)/n-0}\\[3pt]
&=\log(2)\,\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^x\,\right|_{x=0}\\[9pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\log(2)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: One should say that $x^{-1 + 1/n}$ converges uniformly to $x^{-1}$ on $[1,2]$ because $$ \sup_{x \in [1,2]} \left\lvert \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^{1 - 1/n}} \right\rvert = \sup_{x \in [1,2]} \left\lvert \frac{x^{-1/n} - 1}{x^{1 - 1/n}} \right\rvert \le 1 - 2^{-1/n}$$ since the numerator is biggest at $x = 2$ and the denominator is smallest at $x = 1$. And $1 - 2^{-1/n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.